# https redirects + Cloudflare Page Rules missing situation

Tags: redirects, https, cloudflare

I have just moved my website to https and after some scares it is working, mostly.

I did find out that when I input the naked domain on the browser it is not going to the desired URL, as follows:

- typed URL = `example.com`
- redirects to = `https://example.com`
- desired URL = `https://www.example.com`

The following Page Rule is set on Cloudflare:

- pattern = `http://*example.com/*`
- rule = Forwarding to `https://www.example.com/$2`

On the origin server, the .htaccess file has:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` will refer to whatever host the site was accessed through. ie. `example.com` or `www.example.com`. To always redirect to `www.example.com` then simply put this in the substitution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But unless you had a similar rule before then both `example.com` and `www.example.com` would have been accessible (and possibly indexed). In fact, if you access `https://example.com` now it does not redirect to `https://www.example.com`. You also need the following, in addition to the above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

So, in summary, the first block corrects for HTTP -> HTTPS and the second corrects if the `www` subdomain is omitted. I also removed the parentheses in your pattern `(.*)` since you aren't *capturing* it for the substitution.

These two rule blocks could be combined into one if desired...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks w3d, for the solution and the clarification. As per your side issue, before this it was just a redirect from naked to www, which did work fine.

Comment: Ah OK, you maybe alright then... I've updated the answer anyway.

Comment: Good that you did, you are right about the `https://example.com`. The second rewrite is also needed. Thanks again.